# VBA Conditional Formatting if Cell Not Between

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I need to apply conditional formatting to a cell using VBScript to change the background color of the cell if it's value is not between the value of two other cells:

[image: Picture of an Excel Dialog]

code from the macro

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlNotBetween, _
    Formula1:="=$I$28", Formula2:="=$J$28"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

My conversion to vbscript that isn't working

```
    priceRange = "K"&rowNum + 2
    objWorkSheet.Range(priceRange).FormatConditions.Add Type:=1, Operator:=2, Formula1:="=$I$"&finalRowNum + 1&"", Formula2:="=$J$"&finalRowNum + 1&""
    objWorkSheet.Range(priceRange).FormatConditions(objExcel.Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    objWorkSheet.Range(priceRange).FormatConditions(1).Interior.PatternColorIndex = -4105
    objWorkSheet.Range(priceRange).FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 255
    objWorkSheet.Range(priceRange).FormatConditions(1).Interior.TintAndShade = 0
    objWorkSheet.Range(priceRange).FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

Comment: Have you tried recording the macro for setting up the conditional formatting, cleaning it up a bit and using it as a vbscript?

Comment: I'm actually using vbscript to do the entire thing. I need to figure out how to apply that formatting using the vbscript. The screencap came from the worksheet I'm using as a reference when I work on my generated one.

Comment: This should help you convert your recorded and edited VBA to vbscript: http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/vba2vbs.shtml

Comment: @Alexf11 - If you have no access to any version of Excel, then it's going to be difficult for you. If this is really the case, ask Google for usage of Range.FormatConditions (specifically Range.FormatConditions.Add)

Comment: I have access to excel. The screenshot is of the conditional formatting I need set up. That one was set up manually in the excel file I'm trying to mimic with my vbscript. I need to automate it. If it were a macro that set up that conditional it wouldn't be hard but it was set up manually.

Comment: @Alexf11 So I don't see the problem. Record creating this conditional formatting anywhere and re-use the code in vbs, it's just a few lines.

Comment: @Marek Stejskal how do I record creating it if it was created manually by using the conditional formatting button on excel.

Comment: @Alexf11 On the Developer tab of the Ribbon there is a button 'Record Macro'. It's also at the lower left corner. You may need to activate the Developer tab by going into File->Options->Customize Ribbon. This is the most basic stuff, you should know how to record a macro if you are working with Excel.

Comment: @MarekStejskal edited my post to include the code generated. Working on getting it to work in my vbscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that worked

```
Set rng = objWorkSheet.Range("K" & rowNum + 2)

'vbscript doesn't support named arguments, only positional
Set fc = rng.FormatConditions.Add(1, 2, _
                                 "=$I$" & finalRowNum, _
                                 "=$J$" & finalRowNum)
fc.SetFirstPriority

With fc.Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = -4105
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

fc.StopIfTrue = False
```